# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'deleteRecord'

Tags: jquery, ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-model

I am using [ember-model](https://github.com/ebryn/ember-model) here. I am trying to delete record from array which is one of the node of fixture.

This (`cart_items`) array has `hasMany` relation with model.
[I have posted my complete code here.](http://jsfiddle.net/sachin1989/6WPrR/)
Here, i am trying to delete row from table using following code :

```
 deleteproduct: function(product){
    if (window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?")) {                           
    this.get('model').map(function(application) {
        application.get('cart_items').deleteRecord(product);                    
    });            
  }
}
```

But it is throwing an exception : `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'deleteRecord'`

[Same thing i tried using this](http://jsfiddle.net/sachin1989/WZ2Sq/).
Here, i am not getting any exception but record is also not getting delete.

```
 deleteproduct: function(product){     
    if (window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?")) {                                
    this.get('model').map(function(application) {
        application.get('cart_items').map(function(cartitem) {
        console.log("+++++++++++++++++++++++");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(cartitem));
        console.log("***********************");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(product));            
            product.deleteRecord();                 
        });     
    });            
  }
}
```

I am not getting what is happening here?

I think there is some context issue which i am not able to find out.
Can anyone help me to make this jsfiddle work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `removeObject` instead of `deleteRecord`.

edit: I've updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WZ2Sq/2/), The `removeObject` method is on `cart_items` not on `product`.

Comment: I have tried this but  i am getting execption "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'removeObject' "
I have updated  my code at http://jsfiddle.net/sachin1989/WZ2Sq/1/